# Python MS Excel Read and Write

Tags: python, excel

I have the following scenario to use:

There exists one template excel file with lots of column, each of them has column name. I have some datas stored in MySQL, and I want to insert data into appropriate column. I know MySQLdb could be used to link MySQL in python, but any good way to do with EXCEL operation?

it's different than csv so I am not sure any good solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Comment: @NicholasFlees thanks, actually I need some operation on data, so it isn's simply tranferring data from one container to another.

Comment: Understood. I think that link could help get you started on importing your data into Excel. At that point, you can use Excel lookup functions (or whatever else may be necessary) to accomplish your goal. As the question is currently written, it's unclear what you're trying to do specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following steps will do this work:

1. open MS excel.
2. read column names in excel file
3. write related data based on your data in MySQL.

For step1, may get help from [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.3)

For step2, please reference the following code:

```
    # read excel and get appropriate sheet
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, on_demand=True, formatting_info=True)
    my_sheet = rb.sheet_by_name(u'template name')

    # get column names in item_list        
    item_list = my_sheet.row_values(1)
    nrows = my_sheet.rows
    ncolumns = my_sheet.columns
    key_index = item_list.index('A')
    value_index = item_list.index('B') # of course 'C' and 'D' if needed
```

For step3, may use index to get value in each row

```
    wb = copy(rb)
    ws = wb.get_sheet(i) # get related sheet to write
    for row in nrows:
        key = my_sheet[row][key_index]
        ....
```

Please see [my application](https://github.com/linpingta/newsmth_ExcelConvertor/blob/master/operate_excel.py) if needed

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.python-excel.org/

There are python packages available to work with Excel files that will run on any Python platform and that do not require either Windows or Excel to be used. They are fast, reliable and open source:

- **xlrd**: This package is for reading data and formatting information from Excel files.
- **xlwt**: This package is for writing data and formatting information to Excel files.
- **xlutils**: This package collects utilities that require both xlrd and xlwt, including the ability to copy and modify or filter existing excel files.

There is a Google Group dedicated to working with Excel files in Python, including the libraries listed above along with manipulating the Excel application via COM.

Google is usually a better source than StackOverflow for this sort of things...